# Does EclipseLink DescriptorCustomizer not support inherited subtypes?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Basically, I have a base class type that describes entities as being not deletable. I use eclipse link's descriptor customizer API to override the default delete SQL and add an additional criteria to only return non-archived entities.

This works for all classes that extend the Archiveable class directly. Classes that extend a non MappedSuperClass that extends the Archiveable class do not inherit the customizer. See my example below:

For what it's worth, I am using EclipseLink 2.5.1.

```
/**
 * Base Abstract class that implements archiving functionality 
 */ 
@MappedSuperClass
@Customizer(ArchiveableCustomizer.class)
public abstract class Archiveable {

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "DELETED)
   private Boolean archived = false;    

   // omitted: getters/setters    
}

/**
 * The EclipseLink customizer implementation (followed their docs)
 */ 
public class ArchiveableCustomizer extends DescriptorEventAdapter
        implements DescriptorCustomizer {

     @Override
     public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
         // omitted: override delete string

         // this is the piece not working
         descriptor.getQueryManager().setAdditionalCriteria("this.archived = false");
     }
}


/**
 * Base class for entities that are stored in the Catalog table. All are archived
 */ 
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Catalog extends Archiveable {
    // omitted: shared columns, not relevant. 
}

/**
 * This class does <b>NOT</b> work
 */
@Entity 
@DiscriminatorValue("CAR_TYPE")
public class CarType extends Catalog {
    // omitted: class details, not relevant
}

/**
 * Class that does not extend the Catalog class but the Archiveable 
 * class directly. This class can be queried correctly with the 
 * additional criteria
 */ 
@Entity
public class Car extends Archiveable { 
     // omitted: clas details, not relevant
}
```

In summary, the class `CarType` **does not** pick up the `ArchiveableCustomizer`. The class `Car` **does** pick up the `ArchiveableCustomizer`.

Comment: This is by design.  There is no descriptor for the Archiveable class when it is a mappedSuperClass, so the customizer fires on the entity descriptors that pick it up.  When inheritance is involved, the root has a descriptor and the customizer fires on it, but each subclass has its own descriptor, and would need their own customizer class.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for a response. I updated my example as it had an error in it. This may clarify or change your response.

Comment: It does not, and confirms my explanation.  MappedSuperClass classes do not have descriptors themselves, so all settings are pulled from them and applied to subclass entity descriptors.  Customizers are not inheritable though, and are only executed on the entity they assigned to - this is different from JPA event listeners which do apply to subclasses.   Also note that some changes in the root entity will be seen in subclasses; inheritance graphs all use the same cache for instance, and changes to common mappings might be visible on child descriptors though I'm unsure of that point.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the clarification. I found an eclipse link bug report describing the same issue. However, no one from the project has responded. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422232 Why don't you go ahead and copy your comment to an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the internals of EclipseLink, MappedSuperClass classes do not have descriptors themselves, so all settings are pulled from them and applied to subclass entity descriptors - including customizers.

With inheritance, each entity in the hierarchy has its own descriptor, and while mappings and other settings are inherited, descriptor customizers are only executed on the descriptor they assigned to - the root in this case. Also note that some changes in the root entity will be seen in subclasses; inheritance graphs all use the same cache for instance, and changes to common mappings might be visible on child descriptors though I'm unsure of that point

Comment: Just a followup question. I applied the `@Customizer` to the `CarType` class, but yet, the models do **not** apply the additional criteria as specified in my `Archiveable` class. It would be expected that if I directly specify the `@Customizer` on the `CarType` class that the descriptor would be applied correct?